# elmah, stop logging errors from other sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

We have elmah implemented on one site on our server.  There is another site on the server where elmah is not configured.  However, elmah is recording a lot of errors that are being thrown on the other site.

Is there a way to filter these exceptions out from a specific site?

Comment: How do you mean "other site"? ELMAH needs to be configured in your web.config, your app wouldn't know how to use ELMAH otherwise. Are they running in the same app pool?

Comment: I believe it is in a different pool.  I cannot verify now.  It is labeled as a different site in IIS.

Comment: Did you have it configured in the machine.config? that would explain why the 'not'-configured site also throws elmah errors